# how to update previewState of string and keep last value

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, state

i have state of string :

```
  const [selectQuery, setSelectQuery] = useState("lastValue");
```

how can i update the state with some value when `onChange` and keep the last state("lastValue")

here is what i tries with no success:

```
onChange={(e) => setSelectQuery((prevState) => prevState + e.target.value  )
```

it is not working good...

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
const [state, setState] = useState("");

let onChange = (e) => {
  let oldValue = state; 
  let newValue = e.target.value;
  setState(newValue)
};

<Input type="text" value={state} onChange={onChange}></Input>;
```

Comment: why need oldValue ? your code not working...

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(()=>{
...

}, [selectQuery])
```

Did you try useEffect?

If you just want to update when selectQuery is triggered that's probably it.

Comment: it is now about my questing